# How to filter a multidimensional array using appscript

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, filter

This is my array look like

Sn...class... Name...roll... admission

1. ```
   1      X      2      111
   ```
2. ```
   2      Y      8      147
   ```
3. ```
   3      Z      7      456
   ```
4. ```
   1      P      6      257
   ```
5. ```
   1      O      5      678
   ```
6. ```
   9      Y      3      789
   ```
7. ```
   4      I     19      679
   ```
8. ```
   5      H     14      101
   ```

Now I have to filter this data by class like how many student have in class 1 and then I only want to get the admission no. of all those students which belong to class 1. which is [111,257,678] in this case how can I do that beacsue when I use the filter method I am also getting the class like [[1,111],[1,257]] but I only want their admission no. without the class no.?

Comment: `This is my array look like` - that's not what an array looks like in Javascript - make it easy on us, show the array like it would appear in javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to chain [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method calls like this.

```js
const data = [
  [1, 1, 'X', 2, 111],
  [2, 2, 'Y', 8, 147],
  [3, 3, 'Z', 7, 456],
  [4, 1, 'P', 6, 257],
  [5, 1, 'O', 5, 678],
  [6, 9, 'Y', 3, 789],
  [7, 4, 'I', 19, 679],
  [8, 5, 'H', 14, 101]
]
const res = data
  .filter((item) => item[1] === 1)
  .map((item) => item[4])

console.log(res)
```

The resulting array is `[ 111, 257, 678 ]`.

The answer greatly depends on the data structure. Anyway, I hope you understand the idea behind the method calls chaining to form the intended result.

Comment: Nice! Could you please accept the answer? Then people will not check the question when they see it has the accepted answer.